# boost message queue crashes when sending a string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I am trying to pass a string content to another process using boost interprocess message_queue. I have no issue when I pass integers, but when I want to pass the buffer underlying a std::string an exception is thrown

`boost::interprocess_exception::library_error`

Code is below.
What could be the reason for this crash?

```
  // SENDER process
  //
  message_queue::remove("messagequeue");

  //Create a message_queue.
  message_queue mq (create_only,"messagequeue",100,sizeof(char));
  std::string text("ciao");
  mq.send(text.data(), text.size(), 0);
  sleep(100);


  // RECV process
  //
  void get()
  {
    message_queue mq(open_only,"messagequeue");
    unsigned int priority;
    message_queue::size_type recvd_size;

    std::string message;
    message.resize(100);
    mq.receive(&message[0], 100, recvd_size, priority);
    message.resize(recvd_size);
    std::cout << message << std::endl;

    sleep(100000);
  }

  int main()
  {
    boost:: thread t;
    t = boost::thread(get);
    t.join();
    return 1;
  }
```

Comment: I think there might be several issues with your code. Sending `text.size()` does not send the terminating zero. I would also avoid using `message[0]` construct when receiving. If you want to do that, use a vector instead. `.data()` is cleaner, too. Don't forget about the terminating zero when you translate the vector into a string, too.

Comment: same issue. Nothing has changed. Below my code.

      std::vector<char> data;
      data.push_back('c');
      data.push_back('i');
      data.push_back('a');
      data.push_back('o');
      data.push_back('\n');

      mq.send(data.data(), data.size(), 0);

Comment: @AdrianRoman there is no terminating NUL (at least, no meaningful one, the one that std::string adds is purely for legacy interop). In fact, there can be many NUL characters inside the string

Comment: That is true and irrelevant. You can still overrun a buffer if you do accesses like this: `&message[0]`. lakeweb gave the correct answer. I just briefly looked over the code and noticed the address usage, which can be dangerous. That wasn't the case here, where the problem was somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you create the message queue you have `sizeof( char )` but you are trying to put 4 char in the buffer. Tracing reviles the exception is at:

```
   if (buffer_size > p_hdr->m_max_msg_size) {
      throw interprocess_exception(size_error);
   }
```

In message_queue.hpp. With:

```
bi::message_queue mq( bi::open_or_create,"messagequeue", 100, 4 );
```

it works for "ciao".

Comment: It may or may not be filled with the NUL terminator. Regardless, `std::cout << s;` likely simply implemented like `std::cout.write(s.data(), s.size())`. No NUL terminator involved, ever. It's about size, not sentinels in C++

Comment: Hi sehe, according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/) the buffer will be filled with null characters on a 'string::resize' while interprocess will just do a memcpy of the payload. At that, the second resize was not needed. I think you misread what I meant, or I don't get it.

Comment: `ciao` doesn't print without trailing characters because of fact the buffer is zeroed. It prints without trailing characters because the length of the string is 5 bytes (it would not print trailing garbage even if the resize would not zero the buffer)

Comment: Ah, I get it now. because [xsputn](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/xsputn/) uses string size or the null char, which ever comes first. Thanks.

Comment: Erm. Nah. It [does **not** use the null char](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sputn). Even cplusplus.com got _that_ right in the page you linked. *Edit*: **[proof of the pudding](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6050d9205467269)**

Comment: Hi sehe, my brain must have really wanted relevance for that null terminator so I miss read the link. I've removed that update as it is wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah!Ah! Thank you very much! I misunderstood the meaning of the last argument. I thought that boost IPC would have allocated 100 times the size of a char and then I would have written there as in a buffer. Instead the meaning is the size of the single write. Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated! best